# Drawing n numbered balls until a ball is drawn again

Tags: combinatorics

In a container there are n balls numbered from 1 to n. You always pick a ball at random and write down the number. Then you put the ball back and draw another ball. You continue until you draw a previously drawn ball for the second time. What is the expected value of the number of draws?

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.

Comment: This is a version of the birthday problem.

Comment: It is easy to calculate P(X=k).